# ajax post in jquery sends request using GET method instead of POST when the web application is run in any browser in IOS system

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, post

Morning to the whole community. i have a web application that interacts with a backend server (php). When a post request of a form is done using jquery ajax, the request is sent using a GET method instead of POST method. The problem i face is that it occurs only in IOS. Also the browsers in the IOS operating system act the same way but on andriod plateform it works perfectly fine. Please can someone help me out ? I tried to add no-cache option but it doesn't work.

This is the JS code

```
$('#visitorform').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://agri-culture.co/e-training/visiteurs/visiteurs.php",
                data: submittedData
            }).done(function (data) {
                //
            }).fail(function (data) {
                //
            })
});
```

This is the HTML code

```
<form id="visitorform" method="POST">
     <input type="text" id="vfirstname" name="vfirstname" placeholder="Name" required>

     <input type="text"  id="vlastname" name="vlastname" placeholder="lastname" required>

     <input type="telephone" id="vphone" name="vphone"  min="9" max="9" required>
                                                     
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up">
                                                       
</form>
```

Comment: _“This is the JS code”_ - and that executes where/when? Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, not just snippets that lack important context.

Comment: Right now my guess would be, that your JS doesn’t do anything at all - so your form submits normally, and since no `method` attribute was specified, it will do so using GET. (Which you can easily verify, by _adding_ `method="post"` to your form - if you see the whole thing making a POST request _then_, that confirms you are dealing with a _normal_ submit.)

Comment: i add post but it behave the same. My JS code is used when the user submit the form. I had an EventListener to catch the submission of the form. Then it's handle by the JS code. Both of them (JS code en HTML code) are in the same file.

Comment: Same file does not matter, if the order is wrong.